# Checkbox is not functional on converting PyScript to Exe using Cx_Freeze

Tags: python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am creating a Python GUI using Tkinter with Python 2.7. The value of the checkbox needs to be registered in a variable and displayed to the user. On running the script file, the checkboxes work absolutely fine and its value is recorded.

However, after converting it to exe using Cx_Freeze, the checkbox though ticked for 1, does not indicate that value. It records 0, instead. Here is an excerpt of the code for the checkbutton portion. Please help.

```
    global On_Off
    global CheckVar1

    global On_Off_state
    def On_Off_state(*args):
         On_Off = CheckVar1.get()

    On_Off = 0

    CheckVar1 = IntVar()

    CheckVar1.trace_variable("w", On_Off_state)

    global OnOff
    OnOff = Checkbutton(label2, text = "On", variable = CheckVar1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width = 10,anchor = W, bg = '#0e5dd6', disabledforeground = '#FFFFFF')
    OnOff.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = 10, sticky = W)

    global change_On_Off_state
    def change_On_Off_state(*args):
        CheckVar1.set(*args)

    global set_value1
    def set_value1():
        global row_OnOff
        global col_OnOff
        change_On_Off_state(CheckVar1.get())
        d = CheckVar1.get()
```